# How can I replace '%2' with '+' when using http_build_query?

Tags: php

I'm using the Indeed api and I have an array that looks like this:

```
$request = [
    'useragent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
    'userip' => 1.2.3.4,
    'q' => 'agricultural+OR+agriculture+OR+agronomic+OR+farm+OR+farming+OR+harvesting+OR+horticulture+OR+livestock',
]
```

When i use `http_build_query()` it removes the '+' and replaces them with '%2' in the 'q' part of the query.

```
print('?'.http_build_query($request));
// ?useragent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28Macintosh%3B%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010_12_6%29%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20%28KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko%29%20Chrome%2F74.0.3729.169%20Safari%2F537.36&userip=1.2.3.4q=agricultural%2BOR%2Bagriculture%2BOR%2Bagronomic%2BOR%2Bfarm%2BOR%2Bfarming%2BOR%2Bharvesting%2BOR%2Bhorticulture%2BOR%2Blivestock
```

The Indeed API does not work if you use '%2' in the 'q' part of the query. I went to do a string replace but that interfared with the 'useragent' part of the query.

What can I do so that my query will correctly have '+' in the 'q' part of the query? Should I just build it myself manually?

Comment: \*`%2B`, not just `%2`.

Comment: You shouldn't have `+` in the `q` value in the first place. That's the URL encoding of a space character, you don't need to encode twice.

Comment: The user agent value is *not* URL encoded, while `q` is already URL encoded. You can’t really expect consistent results if you treat them equally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `q` value is already URL-encoded -- `+` is one of the ways to encode a space in a URL (it can also be encoded as `%20`). Then when you call a function like `http_build_query()`, it gets encoded a second time, but the API doesn't expect it to be double-encoded.

You shouldn't encode `$request['q']` in the first place. If you can't fix the source, you can decode it first:

```
$request['q'] = urldecode($request['q']);
print('?'.http_build_query($request));
```

Comment: That will result in the spaces getting percent-encoded though, which the target server may or may not expect.

Comment: @deceze It definitely should.

Comment: Sure, it *might work*. Just pointing out that it mightn’t, as it differs from the apparently working version.

Comment: Anything can break in the presence of bugs, it's not possible to protect against everything. I assume conformance to standards.

Comment: Yes, this was the right answer. I didn't realise I was encoding it twice. Thanks! I had a bit of code that I missed that was encoding my `useragent` with '+' already which threw me off.